# $A+A^T=I$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, show that $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}+\alpha i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I tried to solve it but I got $\lambda =\frac{1}{2}$ without the complex part, I'd like to know where my logic is flawed.

Assume $v$ is the eigenvector associated with lambda, then:

$(A+A^T)v=Iv$ which quickly implies that $2\lambda v=v$ and so $(2\lambda -1)v=0$.

since $v$ isn't the zero vector (zero can't be an eigenvector by definiotion), we get $2\lambda =1 $ and so $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}$. I don't see where the imaginary part comes in.

Comment: If $v$ is an eigenvector to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, it need not be an eigenvector to the same eigenvalue of $A^T$.

Comment: Oh yes I see...

Comment: hint: $2iA-iI$ is Hermitian (supposing that by $A^T$ you mean ${\bar{A}}^T$)

Comment: your assumption is incorrect. by $A^T$ I mean the transpose of $A$, no changing signs of imaginary part

Comment: The claim is not true, unless you assume that $A$ is real. Otherwise you can try for example
$$A=\pmatrix{1/2&i\cr-i&1/2\cr}$$ that has eigenvalues $\lambda_1=3/2$ and $\lambda_2=-1/2$. If $A$ is real you can write $A=I/2+S$, with $S$ real and antisymmetric. The eigenvalues of $S$ are known to be pure imaginary, and the real case claim follows from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$. Suppose also that $A$ is real matrix (or that you mean $A^\ast$ and not $A^T$). Then we can write

$$((A+A^T)v,v) = \|v\|^2$$
$$((A+A^T)v,v) = (Av,v)+(A^Tv,v) =  (\lambda v,v) + ( v,Av)= \lambda( v,v) + ( v,\lambda v) = 2\Re \lambda \|v\|^2.$$Hence $\Re \lambda = 1/2.$ The imaginary part can be arbitrary.

Comment: Why is $(A^Tv,v)=(v,Av)$ true? I understand why it's true when $A$ is real, but not complex. $A^T$ is not the same as ${\bar A}^T$

Comment: @OriaGruber because I supposed it to be real. I'm not sure that $A^T$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$ for complex matrices (this is true, however, for $\bar A^T$).