# If $A+A^t=I$ and $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$ then $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}+$ $i\alpha$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, alternative-proof

Will really appreciate your help with the below question.

I fount that if and $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $A$ then $(1-\lambda)$ is eigenvalue of $A^t$ with the same eigenvectors.

Also if $A=A^t$ then $\lambda=1/2$. I don't know how to proceed (I want to solve it without defining the standard inner product over V, as it was solved originally)

[image: attached is my question below]

I understand [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655102) using inner product, I was wondering if there is another solution I could think of because inner product it not the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: you wrote "I want to solve it without definding the standard inner product over V" -- what does this mean exactly?  Your problem seems taylor made for a quadratic form argument....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$A+A^T=I$, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, show that $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}+\alpha i$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655102/aat-i-lambda-is-an-eigenvalue-of-a-show-that-lambda-frac12-al) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24A%2BA%5Et%3DI%24&p=1)

Comment: Hi I understand the answer using inner product, I was wandering if there is another solution I could think of because  inner product it not the first thing that came to my mind